# iPhone table view design with other elements on app

Tags: iphone

I am new to iOS development,so please excuse me if my question seems simple.In my app that I am developing I have a text box and button.When user types something in the text box and taps the button a web service call is made and the results are returned.I am able to parse the results and I am currently displaying it as alerts.

I would like to display the results in a table view so that users can tap each row to view the details.How do I create this table view and make it part of my app as it currently stands now?Where will I place it?How will tell the view to display when the results are ready to be displayed,hidden to start with or otherwise?

I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go through some tutorials on UITableViews first to become familiar with how they work.  This one is a bit old, but still relevant:  http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/  There are many more if you search for uitableview tutorials.

Essentially you want to do the following:

- User enters text and taps button
- You'll create and push a UITableView controller, passing the search criteria into the controller
- That controller will pass that search criteria into your model object, which will do the web service call and return a set of results
- The tableview controller will either wait for the model to return the data, or better yet, receive a callback when the model has finished loading the data.  Either way, you'll then use the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods to populate your tableview